# Python and C#: Send email notification if the script fails

Tags: c#, python

What is the best way to receive a notification via email should the script fail? I'm looking for both python and .NET

Is smtp library my only option? Or are there any better alternatives/packages out there which are created solely for my use case? I've been searching online but couldn't find anything solid.

Comment: What language is the script written in? How are Python and C# communicating? How do you detect a failure?

Comment: In Python `smtplib` called in a try/except block works well for me.

Comment: @stackErr I'm talking about two independent scripts - one in python and another in C#

Comment: @90abyss yes I get that. But which one is doing what?